# How to create a pageview using ga() function?

Tags: google-analytics, javascript, google-tag-manager, page-views

I manage google analytics inside google tag manager and I don't have any separated script for google analytics in the head of my website.

I need to use `ga()` function like [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/):

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','https://www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-Y', 'auto');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

See? It has created `ga` right after google analytics script. But as I said, I don't have any script for google analytics. I have just a script (which is located in the head of my website) from google tag manager:

```
<script>(function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
'https://www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
})(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-{$google_tag_manager_token}');
ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');
</script>
```

The problem is, it throws:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ga is not defined

Any idea where should I place `ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');` exactly?

---

It should be noted, when I run `ga('create', 'UA-{$google_analytics_token}', 'auto');` in the console of the browser, it will be created as well. Do I need a `settimeout()` ?